# Writing a 3D array to HDF5

Tags: c++, hdf5

I am trying to write a 3D data set to an HDF5 file. The write succeeds and the dimensions are all correct in the file, however, when using the HDFView tool, the data is jumbled, but has a recognizable structure, so I must be close. I can't figure out what I am missing and can't find a good example for writing 3D data.

The data is a contiguous chunk of memory indexed as such: `data[layer][row][col]` or `data[layer*rows*cols + row*cols + col]`

The following is the code I am using, where HDF5_CHECK is a macro that throws an exception on error.

```
const hsize_t dim[] = { rows, cols, layers };
hid_t space = H5Screate_simple(3, dim, NULL);

hid_t dataset = H5Dcreate(file, "dataset", type, space, H5P_DEFAULT, H5P_DEFAULT, H5P_DEFAULT);
HDF5_CHECK(dataset);
HDF5_CHECK(H5Dwrite(dataset, type, H5S_ALL, H5S_ALL, H5P_DEFAULT, data));

HDF5_CHECK(H5Sclose(space));
HDF5_CHECK(H5Dclose(dataset));
```

**EDIT**

I believe the issue is related to indexing. The array in C++ is correct. However, I believe I want to store the Z, Y, X data as Y, X, Z in the HDF5 container. This must be possible using hyperslabs, but I am unsure how

**EDIT 2**

Since the data has structure, I can view the data as an image in HDFView. The following should help show the issue:

**EDIT 3**

Contacted the HDF group and found out shifting dimensions is not possible in the current implementation. It must be done before writing the dataset.

[image: Expected vs Actual results]

Comment: How is `data` declared? What's the intended primitive type for each element?

Comment: The type is actually templated. `data` is declared as a vector, however, in the context of this method a `const T*`

Comment: As the data is templated, how are you defining `type`? Can we also see a sample of the data and its "jumbled" form?

Comment: The method I posted is private to the class with a bunch of overloads (one for each data type) that forward to this method providing the HDF type. The data is jumbled because of the indexing change. Please see my edit.

Comment: I'm sorry, what I mean is that I don't yet understand in what way the data is (wrongly) organized in the dataset. Assuming that each position in the 3D dataset makes room for one instance of type `T`, it's hard to understand why the indexing is a concern. A concrete example would really help.

Comment: The memory in C++ is in Layer x Row x Column format. When I write to the HDF5 file, I am trying to write Row x Column x Layer. Originally, I thought that is how it was supposed to be based on how HDFView displays the data. Therefore, the indexing scheme is changing from `data[layer][row][col]` to `data[row][col][layer]`

Comment: Maybe this is a silly comment but, you have created `dim` as : `dim[] = { rows, cols, layers };`,

Comment: That is what I am doing, see above. That makes the dimensions in the HDF file correct, but the data is not in the correct location.

Answer (score 1):

The elements in the dataset are not in the expected order because an incorrect memory dataspace was specified.

The [user guide](https://support.hdfgroup.org/HDF5/doc1.6/UG/12_Dataspaces.html) in section 4 shows how HDF5 can read between two dataspaces of the same overall size, but with swapped dimensions from file to memory. In practice, the [`H5Dwrite`](https://support.hdfgroup.org/HDF5/doc1.6/RM_H5D.html#Dataset-Write) function is declared like this:

```
herr_t H5Dwrite(hid_t dataset_id, hid_t mem_type_id, hid_t mem_space_id, hid_t file_space_id, hid_t xfer_plist_id, const void * buf )
```

The third parameter refers to the *memory dataspace*, which in our case is not the same as the file's (previously defined as `(row, col, layer)`).
It should instead be defined as `(layer, row, col)`. The same page in the guide clarifies that HDF5 follows the same array storage convention as in C:

> Dataspace dimensions are numbered from 1 to rank. HDF5 uses C storage conventions, assuming that the last listed dimension is the fastest-changing dimension and the first-listed dimension is the slowest changing. The HDF5 file format storage layout specification adheres to the C convention and the HDF5 Library adheres to the same convention when storing dataspace dimensions in the file.

The corrected code should be something like this:

```
const hsize_t dim[] = { rows, cols, layers };
hid_t space = H5Screate_simple(3, dim, NULL);

hid_t dataset = H5Dcreate(file, "dataset", type, space, H5P_DEFAULT, H5P_DEFAULT, H5P_DEFAULT);

HDF5_CHECK(dataset);

const hsize_t mem_dim[] = { layers, rows, cols };
hid_t mem_space = H5Screate_simple(3, dim, NULL);
HDF5_CHECK(H5Dwrite(dataset, type, mem_space, H5S_ALL, H5P_DEFAULT, data));
```

Comment: That did not work either. In fact, it gave (seemingly) the same answer. I added an image showing what is happening and what is expected. I had forgotten you could specify the memory space differently and really thought this was going to work.

Comment: I tried changing the mem_space further to test what would happen. It doesn't seem to matter what I use as the mem_space, the output is the same, even `const hsize_t mem_dim[3] = { layers * rows * cols, 1, 1 };`

Comment: That is intriguing indeed. HDFView should allow you to assign each image dimension when opening a dataset as an image. Have you tried every possible combination from there? We cannot be that far from solving this "riddle". :)

Comment: I have tried quite a few. I think I need to hyperslab the file_space since it is in a different configuration than the memory space. I've been trying, but with no luck. The documentation is ambiguous and there are no 3D examples like this.